# University network crashes phone

Tags: wi-fi, crashes

At my college the Wi-Fi uses WPA2 Enterprise to secure the connection. I log in with a username and password. My phone (LG Optimus Elite, Android 2.3.7) successfully connects to the network, and I can use it for an arbitrary amount of time before the phone suddenly crashes and reboots. I've successfully used the phone on other wireless networks, so i know that's not the problem.

Any ideas?

The specific configuration of the network is below (per the university's directions)

```
EAP method: PEAP
Phase 2 Authentication: MSCHAPV2
CA Certificate: unspecified
User certificate: unspecified
Identity: MyUserName
Anonymous Identity: Blank
Password: MyPassword
```

Edit: Common times when phone crashes (only on university Wi-Fi, never any other time)

- Loading/Panning in Maps
- During unlock
- Loading a webpage
- ...randomly when I'm not doing anything

Comment: Does the phone run slower or get hot while on the University WiFi?

Comment: I noticed it heating up every now and then, but I assumed it was because I set it next to my laptop - but    it has heated up. Haven't noticed much of a slowing though - fwiw, i'll update the question and add some specific instances in which it's crashed.

Comment: I did a little digging and found [this](http://www.net.princeton.edu/android/android-stops-renewing-lease-keeps-using-IP-address-11236.html), which might be the problem but doesn't mention the phone actually crashing.

Comment: My only speculation is that faulty hardware or buggy software/drivers may have an issue with the extra authentication and it's causing the phone to overheat. The extra auth shouldn't be a problem, but who knows. It's very strange that it only happens on that WiFi network.

Comment: Hmm...it's possible (total speculation here) that your phone is retaining an IP after letting it expire, someone else gets that IP, and then your phone gets overwhelmed by incorrectly routed traffic. That said, I doubt it.

Comment: I have the exact same same phone and the exact same problem and the funny thing is, it crashes in the university network too :) I have resorted to using the other network that requires a web page sign in.

Comment: Sound like kernel panic, do you have wifi calling or other apps that are known to have buggy kernel modules?

Comment: If this is still relevant, I think we'd need more info.  Have `logcat` being written to file for example so we can see what was happening before the crash.